# Spring MVC Hibernate - Save object with multiple checkboxes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to understand how can I save an employee with multiple tasks. But I don't know even how to start.

[image]

```
// Employee class
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private int idNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>();

}

// Task class
@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
}

// Dao
@Override
public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(employee);
} 

// Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
    employeeRepository.saveEmployee(employee)
}
```

I'll really appreciate if you refer documentation or code of any related example.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a `@OneToMany on a`List`or`Set`in your`Employee` class.

Here is a link to a tutorial put out by Baeldung.com.  It goes over Hibernate and One To Many relationship based on a `Cart` (shopping cart) having multiple `Item`.  Similarly you have an `Employee` with an `Employee` having multiple `Task`.

The tutorial uses a `Set<Item>` but you could also use a `List<Item>` as well.

> http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many